# Is this tv wire dangerous?

Tags: wire, tv

[image]

Hi I needed a tv for my ps2 and GameCube as they look blurry on HD TVs, I dug this tv out of the spare room but unfortunately whoever put it away just dumped it there without paying attention to the wire, I think the tv was on the power lead thus the dents and the cut.

Now the tv works fine and I’ve had a closer look at the lead, the copper doesn’t seem to be damaged it’s not sticking out or anything like that, but it seems the blue and brown (I think) casing around the copper has been “grazed” so a tiny bit of the copper is exposed.

Should I be worried? Is it dangerous? Or could I just patch it up with some electric tape?

Comment: Yes! Replace the cord!

Comment: Exposed copper means it's absolutely dangerous. Breaks in the outer insulation mean it's only a matter of time before it becomes dangerous.

Comment: Is this power cord?

Comment: Yes it’s a power cord

Comment: Then I second the above comments.

Comment: But since the copper is not actually damaged nor sticking out couldn’t I just put some electric tape were the casing is grazed?

Comment: Depends.. which is cheaper.. a new cable or a new house.. BTW I'd also be concerned about the obvious damage on the wire closer to the TV that did not cut the insulation...

Comment: Re, "...they look blurry on HD TVs."  Blurry as compared to what? Blurry as compared to HD content? that is to be expected.  Your game consoles probably will look blurry on an old TV set too, but you wouldn't have noticed it so much back when those consoles were new because _everything_ on TV was equally blurry back then.

Comment: @Trevor_G *a new cable or a new house*.. or a new Potato.

Comment: Replacing the cable is not a big job if you know what you are doing. It looks like pretty standard twin core cable. Clearly you don't know what you are doing so don't this yourself pay someone who does. I would probably charge only a couple of rounds of drinks for my girlfriend and myself if you were my neighbour ask around you can probably find someone easy enough.

Comment: To follow up a little on what James said. Of course the old yellow AV cable is going to make the HDTV feel fuzzy. You're forcing the TV to resize the resolution. There's a thing in image processing called, "rescaling by pixel replication" and that's exactly what's going on with the picture. The HDTV is essentially blowing up the image and "guessing" the pixel values that would go in between the parameters of the rescaled image. It's going to look weird of course. No HDTV has the _perfect_ algorithm to replicate old technology.

Answer (score 5):

If this is the power lead, (not clear from picture but wire colors would insinuate that) then absolutely replace the power lead.

You could carry out a repair, however seeing as you needed the advice of this site to diagnose the magnitude of this problem, I would advise against it.